# How to wire transfer from Europe to a CIBC account please?

Tags: canada, bank-account, wire-transfer, iban, swift

I am trying to receive money from a European company to my Canadian CIBC account.

I received the SWIFT CODE - CIBCCATT from my bank. The company also asked for a BSB NUMBER. The person I spoke to at my bank had never heard of a BSB NUMBER. I have sent them the ROUTING, TRANSIT, and  INSTITUTION numbers. As well as the SWIFT CODE and my ACCOUNT number and added on the bottom a combined * number which I was told what was needed as follows, SWIFT CODE/INSTITUTION #/MY ACCOUNT # = CIBCCATT0105???5?? (the question marks obviously filled in with correct numbers).  Is this correct or no?

I am still receiving emails from them declining the deposit and stating they require more information. Please help me if you can, I am stumped, as well as frustrated as this company owes me this money. OR is there a prepaid card or similar that I can get to avoid this completely?

Comment: that's really weird. a "BSB" is normally only seen in Australia, I think.  it's a old-fashioned six-digit code.   Just tell the sender **you are not in Australia, so of course your bank has no BSB code**.

Comment: Australia? Really? Wow okay, thank you for that information Fattie!

Answer (score 2):

Based on experience I *think* "BSB" is for Australia only.

In fact, if you glance at wikipedia - it does say that.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_state_branch

(Wikipedia is often totally wrong, but FWIW that is what is reported there.)

Solution: talk to the European company and say:

> "BSB" is only for Australian bank accounts.  You can easily confirm this by asking your bank.  We are in **Canada**, not Australia.

Maybe it will help!

Canada / Aus. are both Commonwealth nations, perhaps there was some confusion.